# Highlight Link based on Query string using Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, highlight

I have a menu in the sidebar in a dynamic aspx page. 
I want to highlight the current link based on the query string value.

```
<div id="verticalmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="services.aspx?pageid=11">Medical Transcription</a></li>
<li><a href="services.aspx?pageid=12">Business Transcription</a></li>
 <li><a href="services.aspx?pageid=13">Legal Transcription</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.aspx?pageid=14">Insurance Transcription</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.aspx?pageid=15">Data Entry & Processing</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.aspx?pageid=16">Software Development</a></li>
  <li>  <a  href="services.aspx?pageid=25">Typesetting Services</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, it could look something like this:

```
$('#verticalmenu a').each(function (){
    var linktext = $(this).attr('href');
    if (linktext.search(window.location.search.substring(1)) > -1){
       $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Use `window.location.search.substring(1)` to take the last part of the url, and check it against the `href` attribute of your links using the `search` method for javascript-strings. Then add a classname for the styling purpose. I used `current` for example.

It might need some tweaking, but this is the way to go. However, I would strongly recommend to do this link-recognition serverside. This is a workaround I'm not too proud of.

Comment: location.pathname is not returning the query string

Comment: I've edited my answer. Have you tried `window.location.search.substring(1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Yes i can do it from serverside but i want to learn jquery thats why i asked.

Comment: If there is no query string then it highlights all links. what to do

Comment: ok i got it. i have to check the length--      if (window.location.search.substring(1).length != 0)

Comment: hmm, use `window.location.split('?')[1]` instead of `window.location.search.substring(1)`?